# Connection with SQL*Plus to Oracle

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, sqlplus

I've installed Oracle Database Express 10g on Ubuntu, but the following error occures when I try to connect to sql plus using the sysdba as username and it's password which I gave during installation :

```
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

These are some iformations I think they may help :

`uname -a`

```
Linux aimad-Vostro-1015 3.11.0-17-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 21:53:31 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

`env | grep ORACLE`

```
ORACLE_SID=XE
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server
```

`sysctl -p |grep kernel`

```
kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
kernel.shmmax = 1073741824
```

`sysctl -a |grep kernel | grep shm`

```
kernel.shm_next_id = -1
kernel.shm_rmid_forced = 0
kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmax = 1073741824
kernel.shmmni = 4096
```

`sysctl -a | grep kernel | grep sem`

```
kernel.sem = 250    32000   100 128
kernel.sem_next_id = -1
```

`df -k /dev/shm`

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
none             1014392   156   1014236   1% /run/shm
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: sysdba isn't a username. What are you typing exactly to connect? (try `sqlplus / as sysdba`, logged in as the oracle user)

Comment: what do you mean by oracle user is it the user I used to install oracle 10g ?

Comment: You must be logged in to the OS as the user that installed Oracle (usually called `oracle`), and then run `sqlplus / as sysdba`.

Comment: @Mat well I didn't used the user oracle to install Oracle 10g, instead I used the root user, however when I run `sqlplus / as sysdba` in both of them this is what I get :

`ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified`

Comment: Your `ORACLE_SID` environment variable isn't set correctly most likely. Make sure your environment is set up properly (what you have above looks ok, maybe you logged out and back in and forgot to reset). And DON'T INSTALL ORACLE AS ROOT!

Comment: Okey I'll try to reinstall oracle as a non-root user, one more thing if the ORACLE_SID environment variable isn't set correctly, how can I get the correct one ? because I don't remember anything that reminds me with the ORACLE_SID during the installation

Comment: You don't have a choice with Oracle XE. The SID is XE.

Answer (score 1):

You must install Oracle as a non-root user.  Generally, that user would be called `oracle`, but it can be anything, as long as it's *not* `root`.